# running perl/cgi-bin in Nginx server on ubuntu lucid

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, nginx

Can you give me an exact tutorial on how to run perl on nginx server?

I am able to run perl on apache and lighttpd, but I want to run it in my nginx server because I want to run a file hosting script that is coded in perl and i want to integrate it on my nginx server. I tried following the tutorial on linode about fast cgi but it does not work, i always get a 404 error on my nginx.

so please? can you give me a simple and detailed tutorial on how to run perl/cgi-bin in my nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to process scripts for dynamic content on Nginx you need something like Fast CGI Process Manager http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-php-5.3-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-debian

I had this running with PHP and wanted Perl scripts to run additionally, but then I realised that wouldn't work for obvious reasons (I was having a dumb moment). So, see this question on ServerFault, https://serverfault.com/questions/337404/nginx-perl-not-working, the answer to your question is here: http://wiki.nginx.org/SimpleCGI